Linearization of a quadratic term in a FD scheme
So I have a system of two reaction-diffusion PDEs for some concetrations $C_1,C_2$.
Of course there's a reaction term $-k C_1 C_2$.
I don't want to solve a nonlinear system at each step, so instead I decided to approximate it as follows ($i$ is the time stepping index):
$$C_1^{i+1} C_2^{i+1} \approx \frac12 \left(C_1^{i} C_2^{i+1}+C_1^{i+1} C_2^{i} \right)$$
Then I decided to actually check and it turns out that this approximation has a linear error bound proportional to $\Delta t$, which is very bad as my chosen scheme has quadratic accuracy.
So instead I derived a quadratically accurate approximation with error proportional to $\Delta t^2$:
$$C_1^{i+1} C_2^{i+1} \approx C_1^{i} C_2^{i+1}+C_1^{i+1} C_2^{i}  - C_1^{i} C_2^{i}$$
Now I wanted to ask, is there any way to improve this approximation to maybe get $\Delta t^3$ error?
Seems unlikely, as there are only 3 possible terms linear in both $C_1^{i+1}$ and $C_2^{i+1}$, but who knows.
Maybe there are some special tricks for this kind of term which I don't know about.
Edit: to clarify, I'm using an implicit linear scheme to solve this. I'm aware that explicit higher-order methods would reduce the error to any order, but then there's a stability issue. There's no unconditionally stable explicit schemes, as far as I know.

Is the system \begin{align}\partial_t C_1(t,x) = d_1 \Delta C_1(t,x) - k C_1(t,x)C_2(t,x) \ \partial_t C_2(t,x) = d_2 \Delta C_2(t,x) - k C_1(t,x)C_2(t,x)\end{align}
I guess that involving terms from additional steps may yield higher consistency.

@lightxbulb with some additional linear terms, but yes

You can look at explicit Runge-Kutta methods, although I believe your approximations would be considered semi-implicit here.

My point was that you should try and adapt the same ideas by considering more time steps, e.g., $C^{k-1}$. You can still form a semi-implicit scheme with $C^{k-1}, C^k, C^{k+1}$ and see what you get in terms of consistency. You can try 4-th order too, I suppose you know the finite differences for $\partial_t$ of various orders. I also wouldn't call your scheme fully implicit, since it doesn't involve $C_1^{k+1}C_2^{k+1}$, I would term this semi-implicit.

@lightxbulb, oh, now I see. While I'd prefer a one-step scheme, your suggestion is probably the only choice to increase the accuracy

Even for linear problems the highest you can get with a 2 step scheme is order two, i.e., by using Crank-Nicolson with $\theta=1/2$. So you need more steps as far as I can tell.

@lightxbulb, you're right again

In a problem with a similar linearisation in time, someone suggested this was a form of additive Runge-Kutta method.
